# Want to create live-voice chat between players either in unity or unreal engine

Tags: voice

I would like to create a real-time voice chat in either in unreal or unity between the players.I would like to associate and apply this voice-chat depend on username. I am saying "or" for the application because I want it to create in easiest(less programming) way. Do you know what class or script I should use? I have a limited budget so I am looking for a in-house or cheap way solution of building it.What would be the easiest way of starting this project?

Answer (score 1):

#### For Unity:

[This](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/19344) seems great, but cost 30$.
You can also do it by yourself ([microphone](http://yourselfhttp://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Microphone.html), [network](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Network.html)).
Take a loot at how RPCs works (you will probably have to send your voice data like that)

#### For UE4:

It's fully supported through Steam, but you could use something like  [Opus Codec](http://www.opus-codec.org/) to handle your voice capture and send it over the network.